# Subtract dates By Mongo query by Pikking from Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to subtract checkin date from checkout date in MongoDB

How Can I do that ??

Data from MongoDB :-

```
"timeLogs" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "chekin",
            "date" : ISODate("2017-05-02T05:10:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("590822c66216cf3864740e3d")
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "checkout",
            "date" : ISODate("2017-05-02T14:10:00.000Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("59088037feb56c0fcd60a090")
        }
    ]
```

Any help will be appriciated ..

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: very poor structure. will timeLogs contain always 2 entries ?

Comment: yes i tried with $subract  (it provide miliseconds )and yeah timeLogs always have 2 entries.

Comment: How do you want the format of result? As an hour or date if you do not want the milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how do you want the format, bu you can try those options as a date or an hour.

```
    db.getCollection('Date').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
              _id: "$_id",
              startDate: {
                      $arrayElemAt: ["$timeLogs", 0]
              },    
              endDate: {
                      $arrayElemAt: ["$timeLogs", 1]   
              }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
              timeDiff: {
                    $divide: [{
                        $subtract: ["$endDate.date", "$startDate.date"]

                        }, 1000 * 60 * 60]


              }

        }    

    }
])
```

or as a date

```
db.getCollection('sample date').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
              _id: "$_id",
              startDate: {
                      $arrayElemAt: ["$timeLogs", 0]
              },    
              endDate: {
                      $arrayElemAt: ["$timeLogs", 1]   
              }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
              timeDiff: {
                    $add: [new Date(0), {
                        $subtract: ["$endDate.date", "$startDate.date"]

                        }]


              }

        }    

    }
])
```

For mongo <3.2

```
db.getCollection('Date').aggregate([
    {
      $unwind: "$timeLogs"  
    },
    {
        $group: {
              _id: "$_id",
              startDate: {
                      $first: "$timeLogs"
              },    
              endDate: {
                      $last: "$timeLogs"   
              }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
              timeDiff: {
                    $add: [new Date(0), {
                        $subtract: ["$endDate.date", "$startDate.date"]

                        }]


              }

        }    

    }
])
```

Comment: Error Comming -  `{
                  "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$arrayElemAt'",
                  "code" : 15999,
                  "ok" : 0
                           } : aggregate failed`

Comment: I edited my answer. It seems your mongo version <=3.2 . You can use the alternative one that I have just added.